# Is there and existing Blender renderer REST API service?

Tags: python

There are plenty of Blender renderer SAAS providers out there. But in our use case we need to send a blender file + python file via an API and the SAAS will render, and provide the rendered results back to us. Is there any existing providers for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about using Blender. It might be fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @someonewithpc Seems valid to me?

Comment: @gandalf3 Really? Is it because we might want to now expand the scope, or just in general?

Comment: @someonewithpc If I'm not mistaken, the OP is looking for a blender rendering service which provides a RESTful API. Seems pretty blender-specific, not sure this would be on-topic on SO.

Comment: Oh. I thought it was about developing such a system.

Comment: This is definitely about Blender, we need to render Blender models using python api. We currently do this "in house", meaning on our web server, but we want to outsource this to some rendering service. It might be a bit off topic as it doesn't ask a specific Blender implementation question. BUT, for the blender community I think this is valid, as I doubt we are the only ones dynamically generating images out of Blender 3D models based on customer inputs :)

Comment: I don't believe there is any such SAAS service out there that provides this feature. I'd be very interested in discussing the development of such a service with you. I'm currently developing a Front End GUI for the Brenda render farm package (http://brendapro.com/appdev/), and am very interested in Blender Render Automation projects.

Comment: One of my recent projects for http://Dottlers.com (shoe renderings) involved me setting up a blend file and python script that ran the render on their on-demand AWS server and sent completion notifications to the management app via REST calls. Not exactly the same, but similar.

Comment: Take a look at [Flamenco](https://flamenco.io), the Open Source render management software we developed & use at the Blender Institute.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should take a look at RenderStreet.
I used it for my work as well, what i like about it is that they provide a plugin in Blender, from which you can upload a blend file. Then they do the rendering, they do an estimate of the cost (which can change over time, since your render frames can get more complex); you can ask someone else to pay ahead your render time (ea your manager, or your custommer). And they have web interface that looks quite well on a mobile phone. you can pause / start (multiple) jobs, and they have also FTP access to download your end result.

You might get cheaper elsewhere, but the fact that they offer such billing, and preview made it very easy to combine with real work.
Their support is also quite good, and their speed is blazing.

For sure there other render farms, and even amazone scripts.
But in a work situation this might be as close to saas in a "company-sense-work" way as one might get.

And if you a little bit more time left, you might find an old Coin minner who sells his hardware (that's my current situation), i ussually use that now unless i have to finish something in one day, then i go to a render farm solution.

(oh you might edit the script of renderstreet to make it even more Rest Alike, or ask their support to create it for you).